# Hyperref url fails to indicate correct address

Tags: hyperref

Hyperref links some `\url` items correctly, but others incorrectly.  My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \url{www.swi-prolog.org}
\item \url{www.potassco.org}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Run through PdfLaTeX (via MiKTeX), the potassco URL is set as the expected text with a hyperlink to `www.potassco.org`.  The prolog link, in contrast, prints correctly but internally acts as a link to a local file, in my case, an URL of the form `file:///.../www.swi-prolog.org`.

I have tried adding `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` before loading `hyperref`, and tried inserting a backslash before the hyphen, but neither of these fixes the problem.

Comment: you need to give a valid url, that means with the `https://`.

Comment: Both links worked fine with the provided example even without having to add `https://`. In fact can see `https://` generated automatically in the output pdf links when I hover above them.

Comment: @hesham hyperref doesn't invent a protocol here. In the pdf the URI have only the text: `URI(www.swi-prolog.org)`. Some pdf viewers guess how the link should look, but this only a guess and can be different in other pdf viewer. For a correct link you have to add the protocol.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Funny how the protocol prefix was unnecessary for a sizable number of URLs.